# Error message when trying to read an excel file

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Hi pretty new to angular2 so apologizes if this is something simple - i'm trying to read an excel file using a lib called ts-xlsx and inject the data into the main app root component - The error i'm getting is

> zone.js:355Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: !CompObj is not a function ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
>
> app-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { read, IWorkBook, IWorkSheet, utils } from 'ts-xlsx';



@Injectable()
export class OperationDataService {

    private xbFile = 'test.xlsx';
    private wb: IWorkBook = read(this.xbFile);
    private wbSheet: IWorkSheet = this.wb.Sheets[1];

    objAr: any[];

    constructor() { }

    getData() {

        this.objAr = utils.sheet_to_json(this.wbSheet, { header: 1 });

    }
}
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OperationDataService } from './app.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [OperationDataService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ObjArray: any[];


  constructor(private _operationDataService: OperationDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.ObjArray[1] = this._operationDataService.getData();

  }
```

}

i can't find much documentation on it so any help would be much appreciated.

Update:

Even-though the information online is small it seems that there are a few problems with the way i grabbed the file above - so i re-wrote the service component to align to original alax example converted to typescript

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; import { read, IWorkBook, IWorkSheet, utils } from 'ts-xlsx';

@Injectable() export class OperationDataService {
    url: string;
    oReq: any;
    wb: IWorkBook;
    wbSheet: IWorkSheet;
    arraybuffer: any;
    data: any;
    arr: any;
    bstr: any;
    objAr: any[];

    constructor() {
        this.url = '../assets/data/Operations.xlsx';
        this.oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.oReq.open('GET', this.url, true);
        this.oReq.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    }

    getdata() {

        this.oReq.onload = function(): any {

        this.arraybuffer = this.oReq.response;

        /* convert data to binary string */
        this.data = new Uint8Array(this.arraybuffer);
        this.arr = new Array();

        for (let item of this.data) {
            this.arr[item] = String.fromCharCode(this.data[item]);
        }

        this.bstr = this.arr.join('');
        console.log(this.oReq.responseText);

        this.wb = read(this.bstr, {type: 'binary'});
        this.wbSheet = this.wb.Sheets[0];

        this.objAr = utils.sheet_to_json(this.wbSheet, { header: 1 });
        console.log(utils.sheet_to_json(this.wbSheet, { header: 1 }));

        return this.objAr;
        };
    } }
```

Now i'm not receiving any errors but i can't see the json - any idead what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post your app.component.html. Or at least the relevant part. Besides that you should initialise your `ObjArray` within your `AppComponent`, before you can push stuff in it

Comment: I'm just trying to display the array in a <pre> tag in the template.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, this looks good in theory, but still has a few errors.

- You're using `ObjArray` in `AppComponent` without initializing it, so you can't access it with `[1]`
- The `getData` method in your service doesn't actually return anything

Here are my proposed changes for the service:

```ts
getData() {
    this.objAr = utils.sheet_to_json(this.wbSheet, { header: 1 });
    return this.objAr;
}
```

and for the component:

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ObjArray: any[] = [];


  constructor(private _operationDataService: OperationDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let data = this._operationDataService.getData();
    this.ObjArray.push(data);

  }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks - with the changes i'm receiving another error:

Comment: >error_handler.js:47EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Unsupported file 253

Comment: I never heard of that error - does it exactly say `Unsupported file 253`? I think it's not angular/typescript related then.

Comment: i suspect the error might be coming from ts-xlsx - i'll do a little more digging - BTW thanks for the help..

Comment: I've scan numerous pages and it does seem i was using the read method instead of the readfile  method  `private wb: IWorkBook = readFile('../assets/data/Operations.xlsx');`but now this throws another error `_fs.readFileSync is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

this it's work :

```
Upload() {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
          this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
          /* convert data to binary string */
          var data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);
          var arr = new Array();

          for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
          var bstr = arr.join("");
          var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});
          var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
          var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
          console.log('excel data:',XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true}));
      }
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
}
```